# Why does "rxvt -font x" give me an error, but a "better" font than plain "rxvt"?

Tags: fonts, rxvt

When I run `rxvt&` (Rxvt v2.7.10 - released: 26 MARCH 2003) [which 
seems old, but is the version that ships with Fedora Core 24], I get 
an rxvt window with a font I find ugly.

When I do `rxvt -font x` however, I get the error message `rxvt: can't 
load font "x"`, but then get an rxvt window with a slightly smaller 
font that I really like.

What unholy magic is this and how can I do the same thing without 
getting an error?

I do have rxvt mentioned in some of my .x* files, but nothing that 
mentions fonts:

- In .Xdefaults, I have:

```
 
rxvt*background:        grey 
rxvt*foreground:        black 
rxvt*saveLines:         100 
rxvt*geometry:          80x53
```

- In .Xresources, I have:

```
 
rxvt*background:        grey 
rxvt*foreground:        black 
rxvt*saveLines:         60
```

- In .fvwm2rc, I have:

```
 
Style "rxvt"        Icon term.xpm, SloppyFocus, IconBox -70 1 -1 -140 
Style "rxvt"        MWMBorder, MWMButtons
```

This is the file I suspect the most, but I don't see anything mentioning font.

NOTE: this has been bugging me for the last 20 years.

Comment: What's your question? Why the font changes or how you can change the font? Why do you use rxvt and not urxvt?

Comment: My question is why "-font x" behavior is different from having no "-font" option at all.

Answer (score 1):

rxvt uses **`"fixed"`** if the **`-font`** option fails.  It does this in main.c:

```
xfont = XLoadQueryFont(r->Xdisplay, r->h->rs[Rs_font + idx]);
if (!xfont) {
    rxvt_print_error(msg, r->h->rs[Rs_font + idx]);
    r->h->rs[Rs_font + idx] = "fixed";
    xfont = XLoadQueryFont(r->Xdisplay, "fixed");
    if (!xfont) {
        rxvt_print_error(msg, "fixed");
        goto Abort;
    }
}
r->TermWin.font = xfont;
```

The difference is because the default font is not **`"fixed"`** (an alias for a specific font), but something like

```
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--12-110-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
```

which is different from the actual **`"fixed"`**

```
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
```

(I used `xfd -fn fixed` to get the latter, but you could see this in `/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/fonts.alias`).